# Popular Excel com objeto Java

Tags: java, microsoft-excel

Olá, estou tendo um problema para popular uma tabela do modo que preciso, quero fazer algo parecido com isso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém com meu código só consigo popular assim.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço para formatar do mesmo modo? Tentei pular as linhas pra fazer parecido mas não consigo.

```
public void exportar() throws IOException {

    ArrayList<Dados> array = listaDados;
    String fileName = "C:/novo.xlsx";
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet sheetEtiquetas = workbook.createSheet("Etiquetas");

    int rownum = 0;

    for (Dados dados : array) {
        Row row = sheetEtiquetas.createRow(rownum++);
        int cellnum = 0;

        Cell cellOp = row.createCell(cellnum++);
        cellOp.setCellValue("Número O.P: " + dados.getNumeroOP());
        Cell cellNomeItem = row.createCell(cellnum++);
        cellNomeItem.setCellValue("Código da Peça: " + dados.getNomeItem());

        Cell cellPedido = row.createCell(cellnum++);
        cellPedido.setCellValue("Número do Pedido: " + dados.getNumeroPedido());
        Cell cellCliente = row.createCell(cellnum++);
        cellCliente.setCellValue("Cliente: " + dados.getCliente());

        Cell cellQuantidade = row.createCell(cellnum++);
        cellQuantidade.setCellValue("Quantidade: " + dados.getQuantidade());
        rownum++;

    }

    try {
        FileOutputStream out
                = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileName));
        workbook.write(out);
        out.close();
        System.out.println("Arquivo Excel criado com sucesso!");

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Arquivo não encontrado!");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Erro na edição do arquivo!");
    }
```

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que você está criando todos os itens na mesma `row`. Para *pular linhas*, deve ser criado outra `row`.

```
for (Dado data : array) {

    Row row = sheetEtiquetas.createRow(rownum++);
    int cellnum = 0;

    Cell cellOp = row.createCell(cellnum++);
    cellOp.setCellValue("Número O.P: " + data.getNumeroOP());
    Cell cellNomeItem = row.createCell(cellnum++);
    cellNomeItem.setCellValue("Código da Peça: " + data.getNomeItem());

    // Alinha a esquerda
    row = sheetEtiquetas.createRow(rownum++);
    cellnum = 0;

    Cell cellPedido = row.createCell(cellnum++);
    cellPedido.setCellValue("Número do Pedido: " + data.getNumeroPedido());
    Cell cellCliente = row.createCell(cellnum++);
    cellCliente.setCellValue("Cliente: " + data.getCliente());

    // Alinha a esquerda
    row = sheetEtiquetas.createRow(rownum++);
    cellnum = 0;

    Cell cellQuantidade = row.createCell(cellnum++);
    cellQuantidade.setCellValue("Quantidade: " + data.getQuantidade());
    rownum++;
}
```

Note que, para pular de linha, criei uma nova `row`, e resetei o valor de `cellNum`, para que os próximos valores inseridos fiquem a esquerda.

[image: resultado]

Comment: Fantástico, funcionou perfeitamente! Muito obrigado, sabe me dizer como eu consigo colocar a borda e setar o tamanho da cell?

Comment: Se funcionou, marque a resposta como aceita, para facilitar a vida nas pesquisas futuras! Com relação a borda, podes dar uma olhada nesse link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720049/add-borders-to-cells-in-poi-generated-excel-file

Comment: Já marquei a resposta, mas não tenho reputação suficiente ainda para aparecer, mas disse que foi contabilizado! Obrigado!